# Visual Studio don't recognize new Form Name/reference

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I have a problems wit sencond Form when I want teo open it in the first one.
I do exactly like it is in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIGoSsz5Wwo

Bu when I write: `Form2 openForm = new Form2();` I get an error: The type or namespace name 'Form2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I noticed that Form1 name also don't recognize.
I try to clean/rebuild, delete .vs, bon, obj folders but nothing happend

Do you have any idea where the problem is?

I would be happy any idea and solution,
DomenI

[Form2 code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK4Yq.png)

[Form1 code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMDHO.png)

The problem is with namespace. What is the best way to changeit?

Comment: Either the class name (not the filename) for it isn't `Form2`, or it's in a different namespace. Without the code we can't really help more.

Comment: Can you check what is the class declared in Form1.cs and Form2.cs?

Comment: Thank you, theproblem is with the namespace. Have any idea how to change Form2 namespace?

Comment: @DomenIvanc I think this is not the question to ask , you can summarize easily, just go to Form2 class and make sure  the namespace is same as Form1

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post your code as text. It means we can work with your code to provide you an answer. Most good quality questions get answers within 20 minutes of being posted.

Comment: Let's put this another way: When you do what was shown in the video and when you write `Form2 openForm = new Form2();` it just works. There's nothing in your question that says what you did to make it not work. You should provide us with the detailed steps of what you did to get to the situation you're in.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm new in the forum so I will use your advice in the future. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the video, the form1 and form2 are in the same namespace "ButtonClickOpenNewForm".

But in your demo, they are in different namespaces, "NFCapp" and "Mg74App".

If you want to access the class in another namespace, you need to add reference to the namespace first by steps `Project -> Add Reference...`.

[image]

Then call it through the full namespace.

```
Mg74App.Form2 form2 = new Mg74App.Form2();
```